# Battery ratings for HP Laptops

Tags: battery

I have a HP DV4 1412TU laptop purchased in india. Now my concern is can i replace my laptop battery of 10.8 v 4200 mAh and 47wh rating with a 10.8 v 4400 mAh battery?

Will it affect my laptop's performance, or risk damaging it?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the wattage of the battery could have major detrimental effects on your system. When produced, the hardware within is meant to work with only a specific power level with a certain level of margin. The laptop may seem to work fine for now, but over time it could very well cause severe irreparable damage.